# What may be the reason why SQL Server not running in services?

Tags: sql-server

What can I do with this I have an error on running the SQL Server Express service

> Windows could not start the SQL Server on local computer...

EDIT:

By the way I have looked at the event log and I found this

> The log scan number (85:368:1) passed to log scan in database 'model' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during start up.

EDIT II:

I did all suggestions but it still not running(sql express server service)
 can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: not properly installed or the service account doesn't have required permissions.

Comment: but this was working  a while ago

Comment: what do you think the solution?

Comment: luckily the model database is not a vital database. Try renaming the model.ldf file (and it might regenerate a valid one)

Comment: i tried renaming the modellog.ldf but nothing happens..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To those who has the same problem as mine try doing this. here are the things that i have done just to solve this:

**First:** Go to this path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\Templates`

**Second:** Copy and paste the database/file named model.mdf and modellog.ldf to this path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA`

That's it.. Thanks to those who answers my question..

Comment: it helped me. Thank you

Comment: Thank you!  Saved me from a major headache!

Comment: It helped me too. Thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

If you use the regular MSSQL 12 (instead of SQLExpress) follow the instructions below:

1. Go to folder **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Templates**
2. Copy the template database files **model** and **modellog** to folder **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA**
3. Restart the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) in Services control panel
4. To verify the fix, connect to database engine using Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebuild the Database : 'model'. The simpliest way is to copy this 2  files model.mdf and modellog.ldf from a working instance.

You can also use this command to rebuild system database `Setup QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts [/ SAPWD= StrongPassword ] [ /SQLCOLLATION=CollationName]` [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/us-us/library/dd207003(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: In a _command line prompt_. How you get to that is different for each OS so check it on google.

Answer (score 0):

- If you never install SQL Server on your machine then do not try to
  install visual studio first.
- Always install SQL Server first.
- To remove and re-install you have to remove all the SQL server
  instance and then install.